# How can I configure Fedora to support scrolling with my ThinkPad TrackPoint?

Tags: fedora, mouse, thinkpad

On Ubuntu (and Windows), I'm able to scroll by using the trackpoint and the middle button.

How can I configure Fedora 16 to allow me to scroll with that? In Ubuntu, it just worked out of the box - I didn't have to configure anything.

xinput list shows the following:

```
[jrg@atlantis ~]$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to your Xorg.conf:

```
Section "InputClass"
   Identifier     "Wheel Emulation"
   MatchIsPointer "on"
   MatchProduct   "TrackPoint"
   Option         "EmulateWheelButton" "2"
   Option "EmulateWheel" "on"
EndSection
```

and then reboot.

Answer (score 0):

This should just work out of the box on F17+ as well. It did for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to System Settings and then select Mouse & Touchpad you will see that you are offered options to enable both "Two Finger Scroll" and "Tap to Click." This works out of the box on Fedora 17 & 18.